# Convert SVG to png using ImageMagick 6.9.3-8 Q16

Tags: php, svg, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am trying to convert SVG file with ImageMagick 6.9.3-8 Q16 version. But its not work for below commant.

```
$command= 'convert -size "95"x"95" xc:white -fill grey -stroke grey -draw "'.$path.'" "'.$thumbImage.'"';
```

after expanding above command and try to convert using command prompt its work properly.

```
convert -size "95"x"95" xc:white -fill grey -stroke grey -draw "path ' M 10,20 C 10,20 20,20 20,10 L 20,10 75,10 C 75,10 75,20 85,20 L 85,20 85,75 C 85,75 75,75 75,85 L 75,85 20,85 C 20,85 20,75 10,75 L 10,75 10,20 L 10,20 0,20 0,0 0,80 L 0,80 10,80 C 10,80 15,80 15,85 L 10,85 10,80 0,80 0,95 80,95 80,85 C 80,85 80,80 85,80 L 85,80 85,85 80,85 80,95 95,95 95,15 85,15 C 85,15 80,15 80,10 L 80,10 85,10 85,15 95,15 95,0 15,0 15,10 C 15,10 15,15 10,15 L 10,10 15,10 15,0 0,0 0,20 '" "./designermatthumb/thumb_matdesign_1.png"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command is correct. I had found my mistake. I forgot to set file attribute for folder.
Thank You